# RegisterInputOutput() Error on the Remote Cluster, Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink

Execution of the following code in local version of Apache Flink does not generate any error, but on the remote cluster generates the below error!
Any help is appreciated!

```
 personRecords =  env.readCsvFile("dataPath/dataset.csv")
               .lineDelimiter("\n").fieldDelimiter(",")         
               .includeFields("11").types(Integer.class, String.class);

 partitionedData = personRecords.map(new cleanerMap());
```

Error shown as following:

```
java.lang.Exception: Call to registerInputOutput() of invokable failed
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:529)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The initialization of the DataSource's outputs caused an error: Could not read the user code wrapper: org.apache.flink.quickstart.myProj$cleanerMap
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSourceTask.registerInputOutput(DataSourceTask.java:89)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:526)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.util.CorruptConfigurationException: Could not read the user code wrapper: org.apache.flink.quickstart.myProj$cleanerMap
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.util.TaskConfig.getStubWrapper(TaskConfig.java:284)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.instantiateUserCode(BatchTask.java:1465)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.chaining.ChainedMapDriver.setup(ChainedMapDriver.java:39)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.chaining.ChainedDriver.setup(ChainedDriver.java:78)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.initOutputs(BatchTask.java:1336)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSourceTask.initOutputs(DataSourceTask.java:284)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSourceTask.registerInputOutput(DataSourceTask.java:86)
```

Answer (score 2):

`TaskConfig.getStubWrapper()` throws a `CorruptConfigurationException` if the user code class was not found.

I would check if the `cleanerMap` class is contained in your program jar file.

Comment: yes, there is. and the program works fine while running it  within eclipse or locally installed Flink.

Comment: Running out of the IDE works because the class is already in the classpath. It might also be in the classpath when starting a local Flink, depending on your setup. Both cases would work even if the class is not in the jar file.

Comment: There is just one jar file, do you mean I should specify a path even in this case?

Comment: Flink programs must be packaged in jar files that contain all required classes (incl. external dependencies). Such a program can be submitted to the cluster for execution, e.g., using the CLI client (`./bin/flink`). So the `cleanerMap` class file must be in the jar file and the jar file must be submitted for execution. Which path are you referring to?

Comment: In my program, all of the classes  as well as external dependencies are included within one jar file. In this case, to execute the jar file on a remote cluster, what do I have to put in the class path while running the jar file? for instance in the command  Java  -cp .?.. -jar myProj.jar   I just skipped it

Comment: You should use the Flink CLI client to submit your program to Flink. See the documentation for how to use it https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.10/apis/cli.html. Running a program as `java -cp` requires more manual preparation.

Comment: You are right, this way is simpler. I tried both of the methods, exactly the  same as it is mentioned in the link you just sent. but the problem exists!